# Fetching anchor link dynamically from static pages while dynamically creating href in JSP

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp, xml-parsing

I am working on a JSP file that is creating custom attributes for use in our XML files.
I need to create an `<a>` tag append href dynamically, by entering URL values manually from the static XML Files.

My JSP code is as below.

```
<table class="ptDiv" id="ptt">
        <tr>
            <td class="${ptCSS}">
               <a href="#"><x:out select="$parsedDoc//cp/pg/r/col/r/col/pt[1]" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The XML which I wrote is as below.

```
<r css="row-class">
    <col width="454" css="col-class" colspan="3">
        <pt css="pt">Home</pt>
        <pt css="pt">Companies</pt>
    </col>
</r>
```

I did not had the `<a>` tag getting dynamically created previously, so I researched and put this code. i.e `<a href="#"><x:out select="$parsedDoc//cp/pg/r/col/r/col/pt[1]" /></a>` in the JSP file. I am now getting `<a>` tags appended, But, what I want to do is to declare the `href` dynamically in the JSP page, so that I can manually enter any url on the XML static pages.

For Instance,

```
<pt css="pt"><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Home</a></pt>
```

I tried `${hreflink == ''}` instead of `#` in the jsp file, but I got the output as `<a href ="false">`

Let me know if you need more information for the same.

Awaiting replies. Thank you.

Comment: can you give more information on what taglib are you using to generate the XML?

Comment: Any other ways to achieve this?